# How to get root value of Json get from dialogflow?

Tags: c#, json, dialogflow-es

I got the json response from dialogflow. Now I want to get the "q1" value. So I've tried this:

```
var stringjson = ApiAiJson<QueryResponse>.Serialize(queryResponse);
var deserializejson =ApiAiJson<QueryResponse>.Deserialize(stringjson);

if (deserializejson.Result.Action == "web.search")
{
      JObject jsonob = JObject.Parse(stringjson);
      string q = jsonob["parameters"]["q1"].ToString();
      System.Console.WriteLine(q);
}
```

But string q returns "null". 
Maybe the deserialisation is wrong. The value is embedded in parameters and not the root value. But I don't know how to get the root value of json.
Plus,here's the json response:

```
 "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "search for apple",
    "action": "web.search",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
    "q1": "apple",
    "q2": ""
 },
```

Help!

Comment: have you tried string `q = jsonob["result"]["parameters"]["q1"].ToString();`

Comment: Okay! It succeeded! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
q = jsonob["result"]["parameters"]["q1"].ToString();
```